# Javascript code with 2 classes and issue

Tags: javascript

i have one issue with a javascript code of clicking all buttons in one page.

to do so i have this code

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('A'); 
for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {

         el[i].click();

}
```

But this code clicks 1 button, then leaves one 1 unclicked and after it clicks the 3rd button etc. (it goes 1 click leaves one and then click the other.)

my first problem is this and my second problem is that

if i run again the code it clicks all the clicked buttons. so it has no point.

therefore i checked that when a button is clicked, another class is affected. and I'm trying this code to see if its working but it doesnt.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('num_button'); 
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('num_clicked'); 
for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
    if ( ele != 1)
        {
         el[i].click();
        }
}
```

but its not working at all. it still clicks the button which has been clicked.

Any solution???
Thanks!

EDIT 1: Here is the ***html code BEFORE click***

```
<div class="stats_wrapper num_stats_wrapper ">
            <span class=" num_button  num_stats_span sprite_icon">
            </span>

              <span class="count num_count  num_popup_button ">
                13
              </span>
          </div>
```

***html code AFTER click***

```
<div class="stats_wrapper num_stats_wrapper num_clicked ">
            <span class=" num_button  num_stats_span sprite_icon">
            </span>

              <span class="count num_count  num_popup_button ">
                14
              </span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a demo?

Comment: `ele` is an object, hence `ele != 1` won't work as intended, even if it will procede. Also,it would be great to see the html source, else we are literally working on fresh air here.

Comment: What does your click() event do?

Comment: @loli: I suspect it clicks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click , and I suspect these either are buttons or anchors.

Comment: maybe the code ran into the click events interfers with this code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your issue is caused by changing the button class name, and by that modifying the live collection of nodes.
To resolve that issue you can "transform" nodes to array and then apply the click code:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('A');
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(el);
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].click();
}
```

For second issue (if I understand it correctly) you want to click only those buttons that has not been clicked before.

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('num_button'); 
for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++) {
   var ele = el[i];
   if (ele.parentNode.className.indexOf('num_clicked') == -1) {
     ele.click();
   }
}
```

Comment: Very nice now it clicks all the buttons. Could you help me with the second issue also??? if i run the code twice it unclicks the buttons

Comment: I get this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:6:12
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)`

Comment: Ok now it works better. It only has one issue that leaves some random button unclicked BUT when i put the code for the second time it clicks all of the buttons that are left unclicked. but its not a bit problem. if you have time to check it out ok, but if you dont i accept your answer

Comment: I would gladly help if I could. Would it be possible to see all affected code? You can open a new question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This part is causing the problem:

```
if ( ele != 1)
```

I guess you want to skip the first element, so you could simply replace it by

```
if ( i != 1)
```

but it makes much more sense to just loop from the second element on:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('A'); 
for (var i=1;i<el.length; i++) {
     el[i].click();
}
```